# C# Changing many textboxes' text color on user input

Tags: c#, text, colors, textbox, richtextbox

I have 81 RichTextBoxes in my form (Sudoku Solver), and I would like them to turn gray when user inputs data into them and when there is no data (for example ereased or never was there) to stay white. How do I manage that?

Comment: show us what did you have tried.

Comment: u can use jquery validate plugin. check if it is empty or filled then change colour

Comment: @Sam This is **C#**. I have a feeling jQuery is not an option (hate to break it to you, but JS/DOM isn't everywhere).

Comment: @michaelb958 my bad miss-read the tag thought it is asp.net :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `EventHandler`!
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx)

```
private void TextChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
   if(tb != null){
       if(tb.Text.Length > 0){
        //set color
       }
       else{
         //set color
       }
   }
}

...

//Loop through your controls (textboxes) and set handler

foreach(Control c in this.Controls){

    if(c is TextBox){
        c.TextChanged += TextChangedEventHandler;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1
And loop through the textboes to add them instead of rewriting the adding line 81 times ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".test").on("change keyup paste click", function()  {        
if(this.val()=="")

{

this.css('background-color', '#ffff00');

}

       else
      {
     this.css('background-color', '#ffff55');
 }
})
```

Comment: **-1** As I said to @Sam in the question comments, ***this is C#***, and there is no JavaScript/DOM in sight, so ***jQuery is not an option.***